# number out of range on configuring balances

Tags: polkadot-sdk

I would like to replace the `1u64 << 60` with `x.1` since endowed_accounts is a tuple with the AccountId and the Balance so x1 in the balance for the account ids but after building when i start the node it gives me an error. Someone please help us.

```
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air Xcavate_Node % ./target/release/node-template --dev
thread 'main' panicked at node/src/chain_spec.rs:110:5:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("number out of range", line: 0, column: 0)
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air Xcavate_Node %
```

[github_code](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/Xcavate_Node/blob/2868ef7a53bd6640d32e7030f047fa58bef7d924/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L113)